# What is the equivalent in Azure for SSIS packages?

Tags: azure, ssis

What is the equivalent in Azure for SSIS packages?

So we have got an equivalent to ...

- our web site with an Azure Web Sites
- our SQL database and an Azure SQL

But what about our SSIS packages that handle loading data into our SQL database from various back office systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It depends" Azure Data Factory is SSISish - but it's a lift and shift (ELT) than an ETL engine. Depending on what you're attempting to do, it might be a good fit.

Otherwise, an Azure hosted VM would be your option for remote SSIS. Or you can continue to host your SSIS on premises and use ADO.NET connectors to push your local data to the remote servers.